# How to implement composer in yii 1?

Tags: php, yii, composer-php, autoload

Hello I have old project written in php framework Yii 1.1. Dependencies are added manually by uploading extensions in extension folder.

I want to make my project use composer to track third-party code into vendor directory. So "extensions" directory would not exist.

Existing extensions are not namespaced and are used manually in controllers: `Yii::import('application.models.black_lists.domains');`

So is this possible to achieve and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to require the composer autoloader before any vendor is used in your code.
To do so, you have to unregister Yii autoloader **before** you require the composer one

```
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
require Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendor').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php';
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

After this, you should be able to call any class in the vendor folder, the composer way.

```
new \Owner\Module();
```